# A Problem in Birkhoff Ergodic Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, ergodic-theory

Consider $(\Omega ,A,\mu , T)$ a measure preserving system. Recall by Birkoff Ergodic Theorem for $f\in L_1(\mu)$, $\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} f(T^kx)=\tilde{f}(x)$ a.e.
In the following cases identify $\tilde{f}$ and verify $||\tilde{f}||_{L_1}\leq ||f||_{L_1}$.

1. $(\Omega ,A,\mu , T)$ is Bernoulli Shift* and $f(\dots ,x_{-1},x_0,x_1, \dots )= 1_{ \{i \} }(x_0)$.
2. $Tx=x+\alpha (\mod 1)$, (where $X=[0,1)$.). and $\alpha$ is irrational and $f=1_{[0,1/2]}$.(**)
3. $X=\mathbb{R}$. $\mu$ is Lebesgue measure, $Tx=x+1$ and $f$ is some $L_1$ function.

Note: *For Bernoulli Shift see http://www.impan.pl/~gutman/The%20Theory%20of%20Bernoulli%20Shifts.pdf Page -3.

(**) I find $f(T^kx) =1$ if $0\leq x+k\alpha \leq 1/2$ or $0\leq x+k\alpha -1\leq 1/2$ or ... $0\leq x+k\alpha -k\leq 1/2$.
                                $$0$$ o.w.

For 3. We take some $f\in L_1$, $f(T^kx)=f(x+k)$. If we choose $f=e^x$ and $\mu =1$, the inequality does not hold.

In question 2. $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} f(T^kx) \leq n$ for $x\leq 1/2$. So the inequality should hold, but I could not find any form of $\tilde{f}$.

**PLWASE HELP!!!**

Comment: Please show your own efforts, this looks like standard homework. As usual, we only need to compute the conditional expectation with respect to the $\sigma$-algebra of invariant sets (**only** in the first two problems, the third one is of course of different nature; why is it different?). Recall that the measurability is with respect to the smaller $\sigma$-algebra.

Comment: 1, 2 are done, I am now stuck in 3.

Answer (score 0):

No. 2 is more likely doable.
In No. 3, we have $\tilde{f} = \lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} f(x+k)$.
Then $$||\tilde{f}||_{L_1} =\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} |\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} f(x+k)|d\mu(x)$$
i.e. $||\tilde{f}||_{L_1} =\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} |\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} f(x+k)|dx \leq \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} |f(x+k)|dx$. But I could not find out what to do next!!

If anyone has any clue please help.